# Error Installing H2O in Python - AttributeError: partially initialized module 'h2o' has no attribute 'init' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, machine-learning, automl

I followed the steps given by the site (https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/downloading.html) and install the following:

```
pip install requests
pip install tabulate
pip install future
pip uninstall h2o
pip install -f http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable_Py.html h2o
```

And the terminal return that "Successfully installed h2o-3.36.1.1".

However, when I run the code to optionally initialize H2O in Python and run a demo to see H2O at work, using this script:

```
import h2o
h2o.init()
h2o.demo("glm")
```

it returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mary\Desktop\Algorithms\Algorithms\h2o.py", line 1, in <module>
    import h2o
  File "C:\Users\Mary\Desktop\Algorithms\h2o.py", line 2, in <module>
    h2o.init()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'h2o' has no attribute 'init' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Could someone tell me why I can't run h2o? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you created file `h2o.py` and now `import h2o` loads this file instead of module `h20`. You have to use different name - ie. `test-h2o.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `import` works - it first searchs file `h2o.py` in folder in which you run code. And if it can't find local `h2o.py` then it searchs in folders with modules (in folders which you have on list `sys.path`)

You created file `h2o.py` so now `import h2o` loads this file instead of module `h20` and it can't find `init` in your file.

You have to use different name for your file - ie. `h2o_test.py` - and then it will load module `h2o`

Simply don't use names of modules as names of your files.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the name of the module you have created. There's a conflict.